# How can I solve for all if then statements in a Crystal Reports formula

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

Syntax below

```
if {@BrokerFullName}={TS_ORDER_ALLOC.EXEC_BROKER} then 
    {CS_BROKER.BKR_NAME}
else if {@BrokerFullName}={TS_ORDER_ALLOC.STEP_OUT_BROKER} then
    {CS_BROKER_2.BKR_NAME}
else if {@BrokerFullName}={TS_ORDER_ALLOC.BKR_OF_CREDIT} then
    {CS_BROKER_1.BKR_NAME}
```

Explanation follows

I am trying to run the above formula for all if then criteria to apply where applicable.
Only the first if then condition that is met returns the values.  If I change the order then the first condition met returns the value.

3 fields from table A

```
Broker X
Broker Y
Broker z
```

1 field value from table B

if value of "formula value" = one from the 3 fields, then return the name of the broker

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the formatting edit does not change the issue.  I hope someone has a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

based on your explanation it is likely that all three values are the same, and hence the first values always matching makes sense. Can you add a print field with all 4 values and share the result.